# Find index of same elements in array multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'd like to find an element's **POSITIONS** in same array without methods, with an algorithm...

**Example**:

```
var a = [1,2,2,1,4,5,6]
to display positions of 1 : position 0 and 3
to display positions of 2 : position 1 and 2
```

**What I have done so far:**

```
function count(array,element){
    while(element in array){
        return array.indexOf(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to just pass the array in the function or pass both array and element to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting all positions, you must walk whole array before return

```
var a = [1,2,2,1,4,5,6]

function count(array,element){
  var counts = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if (array[i] === element) {  
        counts.push(i);
      }
    }
  return counts;
}

count(a, 1); //returns [0,3]
count(a, 2); //returns [1,2]
```

Comment: It may, though, be overall better to compute that mapping once and then just return the queried values.

Comment: It depends on situation, if you will search same elements in static array, then you can create map of elements, but for general where you don't know when the array may change, this is only way. You could also create custom iteration that will create map dynamically.

Comment: That's where the "may" came from. Just wanted to note this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
count (haystack, needle) {
    return haystack.filter(function (el, index) {
        if (el === needle) {
            return index;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure it would be faster to call a function for each element instead of just walking it by FOR.